# Subscribe on the route change: flutter

Tags: flutter

In js, I could've listen to location change (route change) simply by using

```
window.addEventListener("locationChange", () => {...}}
```

I tried to use [Navigator Observer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NavigatorObserver-class.html), but it didn't work as i expected; I had to add didPush / didPop / etc. functions on each pages that I open, instead of just one single function that is called on route change.

Is there any similar way to do this on flutter?

Comment: You can create a `RouteAware` widget, and there is an excellent tutorial on how to do so here -> https://medium.com/koahealth/how-to-track-screen-transitions-in-flutter-with-routeobserver-733984a90dea